# Python - Is there a technique I can use for Over Sampling Time sensitive data

Tags: python, oversampling

I am trying to perform predictive maintenance and the rate of failure is 5%. This is time sensitive information and failures occur over time. Is there a technique for over sampling which takes into account the time aspect.

Thanks